# Calculating group mean/medians in MATLAB where group ID is in a separate column

Tags: matlab

I have one column which contains the group ID of each participant. There are three groups so every number in this column is 1, 2 or 3.

Then I have a second column which contains response scores for each participant. I want to calculate the mean/median response score within each group.

I have managed to do this by looping through every row but I sense this is a slow and suboptimal solution. Could someone please suggest a better way of doing things?

Comment: Please show what you have done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use logic conditions, for example say your data is in matrix `m` as follows: the first col is `ID` the second col is the  response scores,

```
mean(m(m(:,1)==1,2))
median(m(m(:,1)==1,2))
```

will give you the mean and median for `1` in the  response score, etc

Comment: From the way you have listed ID and res it looks like they are variable names. However, I just have one matrix which contains both the ID (in one column) and the results (in another). Thus I'm unsure how to proceed.

Answer (score 4):

`grpstats` is a good function to be used ( [documentation here](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/stats/grpstats.html?searchHighlight=grpstats) )

This is a list of embedded statistics:

- 'mean'   Mean
- 'sem'    Standard error of the mean
- 'numel'  Count, or number, of non-NaN elements
- 'gname'  Group name
- 'std'    Standard deviation
- 'var'    Variance
- 'min'    Minimum
- 'max'    Maximum
- 'range'  Range
- 'meanci' 95% confidence interval for the mean
- 'predci' 95% prediction interval for a new observation

and it accepts as well function handles ( Ex: `@mean`, `@skeweness`)

```
>> groups = [1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3]';
>> data   = [0 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1]';
>> grpstats(data, groups, {'mean'})
ans =

    0.3333
    0.6667
    1.0000

>> [mea, med] = grpstats(data, groups, {'mean', @median})

mea =

    0.3333
    0.6667
    1.0000


med =

     0
     1
     1
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a good place to use `accumarray` ([documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html) and [blog post](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2008/02/20/under-appreciated-accumarray/)):

```
result = accumarray(groupIDs, data, [], @median);
```

You can of course give a row or column of a matrix instead of a variable called `groupIDs` and another for `data`.  If you'd prefer the mean instead of the median, use `@mean` as the 4th arg.

---

Note: the documentation notes that you should sort the input parameters if you need to rely on the order of the output.  I'll leave that exercise for another day though.