# Calculating group means with own group excluded in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

To be generic the issue is: I need to create group means that exclude own group observations before calculating the mean.

As an example: let's say I have firms, products and product characteristics. Each firm (f=1,...,F) produces several products (i=1,...,I). I would like to create a group mean for a certain characteristic of the product *i* of firm *f*, using all products of all firms, excluding firm *f* product observations.

So I could have a dataset like this:

```
firm prod width
1   1   30
1   2   10
1   3   20
2   1   25
2   2   15
2   4   40
3   2   10
3   4   35
```

To reproduce the table:

```
firm=[1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3]
prod=[1,2,3,1,2,4,2,4]
hp=[30,10,20,25,15,40,10,35]
x=[firm' prod' hp']
```

Then I want to estimate a mean which will use values of all products of all other firms, that is excluding all firm 1 products. In this case, my grouping is at the firm level. (This mean is to be used as an instrumental variable for the width of all products in firm 1.)

So, the mean that I should find is: (25+15+40+10+35)/5=25
Then repeat the process for other firms.

```
firm prod width mean_desired
1   1   30      25
1   2   10      25
1   3   20      25
2   1   25      
2   2   15
2   4   40
3   2   10
3   4   35
```

I guess my biggest difficulty is to exclude the own firm values.

This question is related to this page here: [Calculating group mean/medians in MATLAB where group ID is in a separate column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14456009/calculating-group-mean-medians-in-matlab-where-group-id-is-in-a-separate-column). But here, we do not exclude the own group.

p.s.: just out of curiosity if anyone works in economics, I am actually trying to construct Hausman or BLP instruments.

Comment: For completion, I am trying to construct a "loops"-solution, but I am having trouble with the syntax for "average all groups but _i_ " within the loop. Does anyone want to try a loop-solution answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a way that avoids loops, but may be memory-expensive. Let `x` denote your three-column data matrix.

```
m = bsxfun(@ne, x(:,1).', unique(x(:,1))); % or m = ~sparse(x(:,1), 1:size(x,1), true); 
result = m*x(:,3);
result = result./sum(m,2);
```

This creates a zero-one matrix `m` such that each row of `m` multiplied by the *width* column of `x` (second line of code) gives the sum of other groups. `m` is built by comparing each entry in the *firm* column of `x` with the unique values of that column (first line). Then, dividing by the respective count of other groups (third line) gives the desired result.

If you need the results repeated as per the original `firm` column, use `result(x(:,1))`

Comment: Thank you for your help! This works great! But, how could I create a vector of the same size of the original data that is: for each observation, I need to have this "other group mean" to run regressions later.

Comment: Is `result(x(:,1))` what you want? This works because the `firm` column contains integers. I have edited the answer

Comment: What a fantastic simple solution! I did not know this type of use. It worked. Thanks!